# How to render html file in Django

Tags: python, django

**In my views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):
  return render(request, "app/base.html")
```

**In my urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name="Home")
]
```

I'm so confuse, it is not working

Comment: Include your stack trace

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Are you getting an error or what are you confused about?

Comment: TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Comment: can you update your file structure in your project?

Comment: @HamzahF there isn't sufficient information for others to help with your problem, since the template might not be rendered due to various reasons. the easiest way and my suggestion would be to follow a "how to render a template in django" video in youtube...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because you didn't add your app in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'mysite', # Add whatever your app is called. in this case it's called "mysite"
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

***settings.py***

**'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your_template_folder')],**

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your_template_folder')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...
    }
```